# Should the FFTW3 plans change for each iteration in a loop for arrays of same names and sizes?

Tags: fortran, fftw

I am working on FEAP8.4 (Fortran) and `FFTW3` library and I am trying to obtian fourier transforms of arrays with same sizes and names. But these are called through a subroutine from the main program. The main program has a time loop. So, for each time step the subroutine is called and then the fourier transform is performed. Now, I declare all necessary variables for the `FFTW3` plan and arrays and the program runs fine.

```
subroutine XYZ()
 implicit none

 integer*8 plan_r2c_p
 integer*8 N
 PARAMETER(N=8)
 real*8 psi(N), psiHat(N/2+1)

 call dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(plan_r2c_p,N,psi,psiHat,FFTW_ESTIMATE)
 write(*,*) 'plan_r2c_p=',plan_r2c_p
```

psi and psiHat are just arrays of N and N/2+1 size.

When I write the values of these Integer 'plans', they change on every loop iteraion(although are of the same order). But my understanding of `FFTW3` tells me that for arrays of same sizes and on the same machines, the plan can/should remain the same. Is this correct? If not, why and how are they changing?

And the reason behind this question is, if I declare them separately and call their values directly, instead of calling a funciton that create plans, inside the subroutine, I might save some computational effort.

Comment: If you perform a FFT multiple times on the same array with the same size (but with different data, of course), you need to call `dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d` only once, before the iterations.

Comment: Please note that you are using an old legacy API. The modern API uses Fortran 2023 features https://fftw.org/doc/Calling-FFTW-from-Modern-Fortran.html The point is to create the plan only once. Creating a plan takes a lot of time, even though somewhat less with `FFTW_ESTIMATE`. But the point is to make one plan with the `FFTW_MEASURE` flag instead, making it more efficient when executed, and execute it many times using `fftw_execute` or `fftw_execute_dft` (https://fftw.org/doc/Plan-execution-in-Fortran.html).

Comment: Thanks PierU and Vladimir for your comments. So, getting to very basic, does it make sense to run a simple code elsewhere to create plan for the required arrays, see the value and just hard code that into this main program?

Comment: No, not at all. The plan value you see is just a handle. It points somewhere where a quite complex  data structure is stored. This under-the-hood datastructure itself should also not be stored because it itself contains things like pointers to other structures. You should always create a plan using the planning routine at the start of your computations and then reuse it in the execute routines.